# O que faz o CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT

Tags: libcurl

Gostaria de saber, o que isso faz:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT,120);
```

O padrão é 120 na `lib` `cURL`.

A seguinte explicação, eu achei meio vaga para mim:

> The number of seconds to keep DNS entries in memory. This option is
>   set to 120 (2 minutes) by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É usado para definir o tempo máximo de vida do cache de resolução de nomes na memória.
Exemplo, suponha que executou o CURL para ler stackoverflow.com.
Será gravado na memória o IP 198.252.206.140 pois é para o onde o nome stackoverflow.com está apontando no momento.
Isso é útil para evitar que, numa segunda conexão em curto intervalo de tempo, o CURL tenha que verificar novamente qual é o IP e isso otimiza a performance.

Uma desvantagem é quando conecta-se a um website de auto tráfego onde coincidentemente o "loadbalancer" desse website, o redirecione para um segundo IP, o que pode causar algum conflito com cookies. É algo raro de coincidir mas não é impossível.
Para garantir que a conexão vai realmente pegar o IP correto, defina como ZERO. Oque vai acontecer é um pequeno aumento nos processamento do CURL pois o forçará a verificar a resolução do nome DNS para todas as conexões.

A definição padrão é de 60 segundos, caso não seja explicitamente definido.
Na prática, não precisa se preocupar muito.

Mais informações na documentação: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT.html

Comment: Eu esperava uma resposta +-, mas essa foi perfeita, muito bom @Daniel Omine, obrigado!